# Can this Regex be optimized?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match the following patterns:

```
#/a/b/c/d
#/a/b/&1/d
#/a/b/c[&1]/d
```

The following rules apply:

```
a) # is the number sign and then its a path. Pretty much anything can be in the path segments. For &1 and []'s, they follow certain rules.
b) &1 (or any number) has to be in a path segment by itself
c) [&1] has to follow at least one character and has to end the segment, only [&l1] is allowed for now
```

So, I came up with the following:

```
^#((/[^/&]+)|(/&\\d+)|(/[^/]+\\[&1\\]))+
```

Seems to be working, but my profiler is showing that its a bottleneck. Is there a way to improve performance or restructure it in a more optimized way? I don't need to capture or group anything, I just need to know if its a valid path.

Comment: Perhaps you could add `[` to the not character class in the third option? Also, pull the leading `/` out of the alternates?

Comment: Well, no idea what the profile says, but `@"\A#(?:/(?:[^/&][^/]*|[^/]+\[&\d+]|&\d+))+\z"` should work well. 240,5 iterations per second at RegexHero. Yours is 116 ips. Not sure how precise my pattern is, I need some sleep.

Comment: @NetMage, wouldn't I need the / to allow for repeating segments?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with it, and what is the other data like - what does it look like, and how much is it matching / non-matching your regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it's very close... its just not handling the []'s correctly... I can put any combination of []'s in the segments when it should just restrict to abc[&1], specifically only allowing &1.

Comment: Adding characters to the negative character classes slows it down, but see my answer on pulling the `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running some quick tests, this is the fastest. I added some brackets to the negative character classes to exclude paths that have extraneous brackets in them. It is faster without them.

```
var pattern = "^#(?:/(?:&\\d+|[^/&[\\]]+\\[&1]|[^/&[\\]]+))+$";
var REc = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Changing the order depending on what type of segment is most frequent can be faster - this is faster on my test data that mostly has alphanumeric segments:

```
var pattern2 = "^#(?:/(?:[^/&[\\]]+|&\\d+|[^&/[\\]]+\\[&1]))+$";
```

Tested using `REc.IsMatch(bs)`

This is faster if brackets are okay in segments:

```
var pattern = "^#(?:/(?:&\\d+|[^/]+\\[&1]|[^/&]+))+$";
```

Comment: Nice! Your first one where the brackets are disallowed except in the proper format hits all the test cases. I'll see if the code runs faster tomorrow. If its still a bottleneck, I might drop regex and do simple checks (i.e. starts with #/, split the string check for empties, etc.)

Comment: Did some benchmarks, my original regex was about 2500 - 2600ms. Your first one with the brackets dropped it down to 2200 - 2300ms.

Comment: Are you using a compiled pattern? Most of the benefit comes from that. How large a group of strings are you testing? I see about a 1.5x speedup from your original to that one, both with brackets. Are you doing something else with the `Regex` than just `IsMatch`?

Comment: I changed my second alternative to exclude `&` otherwise paths like `#/this/&that[&1]` were accepted. That slows it down a bit, of course.

Comment: Hi, that was the full runtime of the method. I didn't break the regex out into a seperate timing test, but the 300ms+ improvement was all from your new regex (20k iterations). Yeah, I'm using the compiled flag. I'm happy with the improvement. I also found further ways to optimize the code and got it down to 1800ms. Btw, I tried writing a simple C# validation method instead of using regex, and it only shaved off about 10ms on 20k iterations, so your regex is pretty darn fast :).

Comment: All the credit goes to the `Regex` compiler writers - it is pretty hard to beat its performance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try would be to tell the regex engine not to capture anything:

```
^#(?:(?:/[^/&]+)|(?:/&\\d+)|(?:/[^/]+\\[&1\\]))+
```

By marking each group `(?: ... )` we tell the engine to ignore this group.